# ASP.NET MVC 3 , 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, hosting, publish

It is my first MVC project and always the first time has pain ;)

I did these steps to deploy project .

1. Used **publish** option in solution explorer and select **File System**.
2. Upload published file to server
3. add these extra files to bin folder

> Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>
> Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
>
> System.Web.Helpers.dll
>
> System.Web.Mvc.dll
>
> System.Web.Razor.dll
>
> System.Web.Routing.dll
>
> System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
>
> System.Web.WebPages.dll
>
> System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

I got this error **404 - File or directory not found.**

[here is the snapshot](http://up.vatandownload.com/images/4u6sie8oxz27ysr3je8e.jpg) of my website admin panel

note 1: My host provider installed the latest version of ASP.NET MVC via WebInstaller yesterday.

note 2 : The host's operating system is Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use ASP.NET 4 (Integrated Pipeline). This allows you to use extensionless urls which are used by default when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application. You haven't told us much about your application so we can only be guessing what kind of routes you are using.

If you select the ASP.NET 4 (Classic Mode) it's the same if you were running in IIS 6.0 which doesn't support extensionless urls and you will need to configure and associate some extension to the aspnet ISAPI filter.

Comment: I've tried to use `Integerated Pipeline` but I get this plain text with this error `Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.` is this type of error related to hosting issue or related to my code ?

Comment: Chances are it is related to your code. Don't forget that in Integrated Pipeline mode you don't have access to any HttpContext related stuff (Request, Response, Session, ...) in `Application_Start`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add dot (.) before the "href" in the Views as below:

> href='**.**/Controller/Action/'